# DC motors in series to get 5 Volts?

Tags: voltage, current

I am trying to build a circuit that has wheels rotating that are connected to a motor. This motor will then generate 5 Volts to a battery which then charges lets say a cell phone. I have two wheels that have motors on both, that are connected in series which is then hooked up to a portable charger and a multimeter. I got an open circuit voltage of 5 Volts but when i connect it to the load (the portable charger), i am only getting about 1 Volt. **How many motors, or of what kind, do I need to get the output to be 5 Volts under load?**

Comment: I am not the best engineer, but maybe a schematic would help clarify what the problem is.

Comment: Can you please specify voltage rating of motor?
Voltage output of motor will depend upon speed of motor. And to charge the battery you need to convert AC output of motor acting as generator in DC for charging the battery.

Comment: DC motor will generate DC current, no need to convert anything.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to understand first is

## How DC motors work

Most likely you have a [brushed DC motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor). It will have an equivalent circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4u3qB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When you use a motor as a generator,\$V_{emf}\$ will increase with the speed. However, V_mot that you can measure on motor's terminals is \$V_{emf} - R_{mot}*I\$. When you measured voltage on an open circuit, there was (almost) no current flowing, so you have measured pure \$V_{emf}\$. When you connect the load, there is some current, that causes voltage drop on internal motor resistance, and measured voltage is smaller.

## How to find out what motor you need?

Assuming you want to use just a single motor:

1. Find out maximum current that your charger will draw, and a voltage that it will require. Keep in mind that some batteries (especially those found in cell phones) can require specific charging characteristic (constant current, voltage etc.).
2. Find a motor that will satisfy following condition: $$ V_{req} = V_{emf} - I_{req} * R_{mot} $$ where \$V_{req}\$ and \$I_{req}\$ are your required voltage and current.
3. You can assume that \$V_{emf}\$ will be equal to motor's rated voltage at no load speed. You can usually find these parameters in motor's datasheet. If there is no resistance given, you can calculate it by dividing rated voltage by stall (maximum) current of a motor.

**EDIT:**

## Series vs. parallel

If you want to have two motors, first make sure that they are both same type. That will not guarantee their specs will be exactly the same, but we want them to be as closely matched as possible.

- **Series connection** will give you higher voltage with the same current, but if you have 5V under the full load, when the current consumed by your charger/battery will go down, the output voltage will rise to 2 times the voltage of a single motor under no load. Make sure that your device can withstand this.
- **Parallel connection** will allow for more current to be supplied. As I have already mentioned, it's the current flowing through a motor, that causes the voltage drop from higher voltage under no load to smaller with full load. Parallel connection of two motors will reduce the current flowing through a single motor by two times, thus reducing also the voltage drop. I would add a diode in series with each motor, to prevent current flowing in reverse through a motor if for some reason the voltages they generate differ.

## Additional thoughts on your device

- From what you have stated in your comment, you want to attach these motors to wheels of a suitcase. I disagree, that they will be guaranteed to have the same speed. Imagine a situation when you turn. Do the wheels travel the same distance then?
- You can push the suitcase backward, so the motors will also spin back, and generate reverse voltage. Are you prepared for this?
- The voltage generated by the motor will vary with the speed with which it rotates. Are you ready to handle situations like walking slowly or running?

Comment: Well the motors will be charging a battery or a portable charger... so the current going into the charger isnt really that important. I would like to get 5 volts going into the battery.

Comment: And there will be two motors. I assume they should be in series since I want the voltage to be higher and the current the same? or should i put it in parallel?

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: @AnthonyKefalos Can you be more specific on the battery and the charger? What kind of battery, and what charger? What is battery nominal voltage, and what are charger voltage limits? Also, will motors be the same? Are they guaranteed to run at the same speed? Finally, do you have any control loop, measuring output and adjusting motor speed to it?

Comment: I probably shloildve put this in the description haha. Sorry. I am trying to build a suitcase that charges a portable charger using the kinetic energy from the wheels. So yes, both wheels will be guaranteed to go at the same speed as will the motors. The portable charger should have an input voltage of 5V. That's why I was wanting to get 5 volts in the first place. The current is not totally necessary for the input.

Comment: @AnthonyKefalos Made edits in the answer.

Comment: is there a way i can contact you directly? instead of having to go through this. if you have some time, i would like to talk to you about this...

Comment: i would like to talk with you and discuss how i should go about these senarios you presented. if you can, email me at  anthonykefalos@gmail.com

Comment: is there anyway i can get in contact with you? i would like to discuss some changes i have made...I posted an email address you can contact me at anthonykefalos@gmail.com... If it is possible, i would greatly appreciate it! @mactro

Comment: @AnthonyKefalos ok, I'll email you later this day. Better remove your address, or it may attract spammers.